# How to traverse a multi-language version resource?

Tags: c++, winapi, modern-ui

I'm trying to use the code snippet shown [at the end of this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to read multi-language version resource for executable files.

But, for example, when I run the code below for this file:

[image]

I get my `nCnt` as `1` for only one resource, i.e. English.

What am I doing wrong?

```
LPCTSTR buff = L"path-to\\file.exe";

struct LANGANDCODEPAGE {
  WORD wLanguage;
  WORD wCodePage;
} *lpTranslate;

DWORD dwDummy;
DWORD dwSz = GetFileVersionInfoSize(buff, &dwDummy);
if(dwSz > 0)
{
    BYTE* pData = new (std::nothrow)BYTE[dwSz];
    if(pData)
    {
        if(GetFileVersionInfo(buff, NULL, dwSz, pData))
        {
            //Get language info
            UINT ncbSz;
            LANGANDCODEPAGE* pLcp;
            if(VerQueryValue(pData, L"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation", (VOID**)&pLcp, &ncbSz))
            {
                UINT nCnt = ncbSz / sizeof(struct LANGANDCODEPAGE);

                CString strQuery;
                UINT nczBufLn;
                LPCTSTR pDescBuf;

                for(UINT i = 0; i < nCnt; i++)
                {
                    strQuery.Format(L"\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\FileDescription", 
                        pLcp[i].wLanguage, pLcp[i].wCodePage);
                    if(VerQueryValue(pData, (LPTSTR)strQuery.GetString(), (VOID**)&pDescBuf, &nczBufLn))
                    {
                        wprintf(L"Description%d: %s\n", i, pDescBuf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        delete[] pData;
    }
}
```

Comment: [The `Translation` table is not always reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953472/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, that is not exactly the same thing. I don't even get to calling `VerQueryValue` on `L"\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\FileDescription"`, the call with `L"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation"` returns size for 1 language when I am expecting 3. That is my issue.

Comment: I understand the issue. My point is, the translation table is susceptible to human error, and it is a  common mistake to code the table incorrectly. You may have 3 languages available but the table only has 1 entry. Use a resource editor to verify. Some resource compilers don't report mismatches like this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to store multi-language version resources.

The best way is of course to have one resource entry with multiple translation blocks. These will be accessible with `VerQueryValue`.

The other way is to store multiple resource entries, one for each language. This is the way you store other types of localized resources (bitmaps, strings etc.). `EnumResourceLanguages` should be able to enumerate them but `GetFileVersionInfo` will probably just pick the language that matches your thread or UI language.

Comment: I see. So what you're saying is that one of my options is to parse PE header manually. (I don't have an `HMODULE` handle for `EnumResourceLanguages`.)

Comment: If this is some sort of PE version viewer/utility and you want to support all version types then yes, you must do some manual parsing. You might be able to trick `VerQueryValueW` on non-Win9x systems into reading raw resource data but it is a bit risky because it might do some extra work in `GetFileVersionInfo` to massage the data.

Comment: No I need it to be compatible with Windows 95.

Comment: Then you must parse yourself, the 32-bit version resource is stored in Unicode and the API on Win9x uses extra data to store translated strings.

Comment: Yeah, dude, I'm kidding about Win95. But yes, otherwise it looks like I need to be parsing it manually. (I just stepped into `GetFileVersionInfo*` and `VerQueryValue` APIs and besides raising & muting all kinds of exceptions internally, they are very inefficient. Each API basically calls `LoadLibraryEx` to map the file into memory and then releases it. Even if all you need is the size of the resource.)

Comment: `GetFileVersionInfoSize` does not return just the size of the resource, it might lie and return a larger size if the other functions might require space to do Unicode conversion. Not sure if NT systems support 16-bit ANSI resources, if not then it will not lie in the W version of the functions.